# React Router, this.props.children == null when refreshing page

Tags: react-router

So I've got React-Router set up as follows:

```
// App.js
render(){
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {this.props.children}
        <Footer />
      </div>
      )
  }

// routes.js
export default (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App} >
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/destination" component={DestinationIndexHandler} />
        <Route path="/destination/:slug" component={DestinationHandler} />
        <Route path="/destination/:slug/:article" component={ArticleHandler} />
        <Route path="/article" component={ArticleIndexHandler} />
        <Route path="/article/:slug" component={ArticleHandler} />
        <Route name='contact' path="/contact" component={ContactHandler} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFoundHandler}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

And finally:

```
// server.js
app.get(/^(?!.*(api|.js|.css)).*$/, function (req, res) {
  let location = createLocation(req.url);
  console.log("LOCAL")
  match({ routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    console.log(location);
      if (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message)
      } else if (redirectLocation) {
        res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
      } else if (renderProps) {
        let content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
        console.log(content);
        res.status(200).render('index', {
          content: content,
          staticPort: DEV_PORT
        });
      } else {
        res.status(404).send('Not found')
      }
    })
});
```

For some reason, when I refresh the page, the server side renders the view successfully but the browser renders the home view (IndexRoute). If you remove the IndexRoute, it only renders the header and footer.

If I log in the terminal I get 3 returns, the first and second being:

`CHILDREN { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: [Function: ContactHandler],`

and finally a call to NotFoundHandler, even though the route is there. Any ideas?